# Azure website stays disabled after scaling out to more instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website in Azure shared mode, and it has hit the 512MB memory usage limit. I went to Azure dashboard, scaled out to two instances from one, saved changes, restarted my site. It displays perfectly on dashboard (no over capacity, 'Running' state etc):

[image]

When I go to my site it displays the default Azure website not available page (tried hard-refreshing my browser too). It has been about 5 minutes, I've restarted several times, but it has not changed, I'm still getting the infamous website unavailable error page:

[image]

Why can this be and how can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the site has exceeded the memory quota that is enforced per hour the site has been stopped for the remainder of that hour. It will be unblocked after that. Increasing the number of workers per site does not reset the quota after it has been already enforced. The recommended way to prevent hitting the quota limits is to change the site to "Basic" SKU, which will remove the quotas and will place your site on a dedicated VM.

Comment: I see. I though that it would continue to run when I increase the quota. Interesting, but I'll take the changing compute mode tip :)